# Creating reusable UI components

Tags: angularjs

In jQuery, you can create reusable UI components. In AngularJS, I understand that using Directives is the equivalent way of doing this. The Directive syntax includes a Link property where you can manipulate the DOM. But this is where I get confused. AngularJS is meant to avoid manipulating the DOM because AngularJS manipulates the DOM internally, so why would you do this? Is there a better way of doing this without actually having to manipulate the DOM?

Answer (score 3):

Where did you get the idea that all DOM manipulation is a bad thing? How would anything ever get rendered if the DOM wasn't being manipulated? It's a bad idea to mess with the DOM in **controllers** or **outside of Angular's context** but in directives you're plugging into Angular and can safely make DOM changes without breaking anything.

You're basically asking how to manipulate the DOM without manipulating the DOM which makes no sense.

Go ahead and do your stuff in the link-function, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: How are you guaranteed to be making DOM changes safely? What if the section of DOM you are manipulating is being manipulated at a parent level by Angular. I can see possible conflicts here.

Comment: The link function is run as the element is attached to the DOM, how would any other parts of Angular be able to interfere?

Comment: If my DOM manipulation modifies the parent class while the parent class is set by ng-class, that would be considered a conflict.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean, but then that's probably something to add to the list of "just dont do that". I can create similar problems in a controller hierarchy if I wanted to. Directives are still the place to do custom DOM operations.

Comment: If you use some third party angular UI code, the developer of that code may not have documented "just don't do that". If you're writing your own, you probably will never have this problem but I have seen jQuery UI controls that do manipulate the parent DOM attributes and styles in code that it gets embedded into, so I assume similiar issues could arise with angularJS.

Comment: I suppose in theory you could end up in a bad place, but that's a common trait for everything that involves code. If a particular component is creating problems for you I'd suggest making a question out of that specific case. It might be fixable.

Comment: I think the key thing to remember is that if you manipulate the DOM, you should only manipulate that part of the DOM that your component is being injected into and not touch anything outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

At some point you will have to engage in manipulating the DOM in some way or another, but for 95% of all cases you can stick to angular's built in directives, such as ng-if, ng-hide/show, ng-switch, ng-repeat etc...

But these are all directives, so angular isn't manipulating the DOM "internally", it does it through directives, just as it's meant to do...

And keep in mind that in your directive templates, you can use those other directives, so your directive can focus on it's own task.

Comment: `so angular isn't manipulating the DOM "internally"` excatly oposite. How do you think anything would be renderd if Angular don't do DOM manipulation?

Comment: Think you misunderstood the point I tried to make there, the ng-if directive manipulates the DOM, the ng-bind directive manipulates the DOM and so on... so there is no "internal" thing in Angular that does it, those directives uses the exact same API as anyone can use in their custom directives... Hence it's very much done in part of the "public" API as opposed to done internally.

Comment: The whole process of compile and link need to do DOM maniplation, it read the html replace directives (run they compile+link functions) and reinsert it into the DOM. So internaly Angular need to use DOM manupulation and directives only add custom DOM manipulation while Angular do the rest. You could say that directives do DOM manupulations (and user code should only use directives to manipulate DOM) but not that Agnular internally don't do that.

Comment: Your talking about the $compile service, witch is also public. That aside, it doesn't actually do what you think for all directives, it depends weather or not that directive specifies a template. If not it actually doesn't replace anything in the DOM. (Not as far as reading the code reveals at least)... it adds some classes and data to it, so fair enough it does internal DOM manipulation, but insignificant to the topic here IMO.

Comment: Initial bootstrapping aside, (which isn't truly calling $compile as from a directive), most use of $compile will be in a directive, and you will actually have to enter the "root nodes" given to $compile into the DOM your self, if they where not already in there. In some cases it makes sense to use the $animate service for that. I say in most cases because I actually think the UI-Bootstrap team extends the use of $compile to services when doing modal dialog's... Not that they had to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $new(isolate) method from the $rootScope to create reuseable UI components. Set isolate to true. Don't manipulate anything outside of your UI component:

> If true, then the scope does not prototypically inherit from the
>   parent scope. The scope is isolated, as it can not see parent scope
>   properties. When creating widgets, it is useful for the widget to not
>   accidentally read parent state.

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

Comment: In directive most of the time you don't need to call $new (unless you translude by hand using translude function) in directive you just use `scope: true` or `scope: {}` the second one will create isolated scope, and you will be able access it as first argument in link function.